# Building Mendel Linux fail

Tags: mendel-os

I follow the [Getting Started with Mendel Linux](https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md) document to build the Mendel linux.
I successfully built it before but I could not rebuild it since December, 2021.
I check the uboot-imx-arm64.log and I guess there is an error while building uboot.

```
...
 dpkg-source --after-build .
 lintian --profile=mendel ../uboot-imx_5-3_arm64.changes
dpkg-buildpackage: info: full upload (original source is included)
N: 1 tag overridden (1 error)
[0mI: Copying back the cached apt archive contents[0m
[0mI: unmounting /rootdir/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell/packages filesystem[0m
[0mI: unmounting /rootdir filesystem[0m
[0mI: unmounting dev/ptmx filesystem[0m
[0mI: unmounting dev/pts filesystem[0m
[0mI: unmounting dev/shm filesystem[0m
[0mI: unmounting proc filesystem[0m
[0mI: unmounting sys filesystem[0m
[0mI: cleaning the build env [0m
[0mI: removing directory /rootdir/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell/obj/PBUILDER/2051 and its subdirectories[0m
[0mI: Current time: Wed Mar 16 07:34:56 UTC 2022[0m
[0mI: pbuilder-time-stamp: 1647416096[0m
```

But I don't see any description about error.

I also try to use [the last uboot](https://coral.googlesource.com/uboot-imx/+/cd03c4eed999955581e4a3d9e232df0aa01f1428) to instead.
I can't even see uboot-imx-arm64.log after building.

Does anyone face similar problem?

Comment: I check the file, out/buildtab.  The last line show me sub-build failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone
I notice that there are some certificate issue.
Since the build process is running in docker.

The Docker will Add build folder content,
so I add below command into /build/setup.sh

```sh
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
```

And rebuild the Mendel, everything is work again.